# Problems changing ownership from service account to google apps domain

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an app that uses a Google Service Account to create either a Fusion Tables or Google Spreadsheet document.  This app  then changes the ownership of that document to another user (joe@gmail.com). This enables the app to publish (insert rows) to the document, but gives full control over the document to the specified user.

Everything works fine if the other user is an @gmail.com user. However, if it is an apps domain user (e.g., xxx@camfed.org), the permission change results in this error:

{ "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "internalError",    "message": "Internal Error"   }  ],  "code": 500,  "message": "Internal Error" }}{"value":"xxx@camfed.org","role":"owner","type":"user","kind":"drive#permission"}

Here is the outcomes matrix:

```
                                               Service Account created by
                                           xxx@gmail.com           xxx@camfed.org

Ownership assigned to: yyy@gmail.com           works                     works
Ownership assigned to: xxx@camfed.org         broken                     broken
Ownership assigned to: yyy@camfed.org         broken                     broken
```

Are Google Drive permissions changes broken for apps domains?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because I am not the admin and can't verify if this is a solution or not. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) looks to be some instruction on delegating domain access to service accounts. I could be wrong, but it may help. Please let me know if this works for you. These are instructions for `Google Drive API` but all the api platforms have scopes that can be added.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to that when changing ownership, the both email-domain must belong to the same domain. Then it is possible to change the ownership to the other user.

Comment: Not entirely true.  The service account e-mail address is:
322...h@developer.gserviceaccount.com

And it has no trouble reassigning ownership to @gmail.com accounts.
The problem is that it cannot reassign ownership to Google Apps accounts.

Comment: While the wording of the answer above was a little off, it is correct in spirit. It's currently not possible to reassign ownership of a document to a google apps domain from outside that domain.

Comment: Not quite correct either. Note that if you start with a service account created by a camfed.org user (xxx@@camfed.org), that service account still cannot assign ownership to another user within the @camfed.org organization. The service account is apparently tainted by being in the 'developer.gserviceaccount.com' domain and does not retain the fact that the creator of the account was in the 'camfed.org' domain and that the service account should therefore have privileges within that domain and not within the gmail.com domain.